# Can I write cls files in LaTeX instead of TeX?

Tags: latex, xelatex

I have some initialization code in a XeLaTeX file which I would like to put into a separate file so that I can reuse it in future texts. What is the fastest way to convert my XeLaTeX code to a LaTeX class file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put your preamble code into a `.cls` file and then use `\documentclass{mydocstyle}` to load it. Your `.cls` file will look like this:

```
% Declare that this document class file requires at least LaTeX version 2e.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% Provide the name of your document class, the date it was last updated, and a comment about what it's used for
\ProvidesClass{mydocstyle}[2010/09/13 Bluetulip's custom LaTeX document style]

% We'll pass any document class options along to the underlying class
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}% or book or whatever
}

% Now we'll execute any options passed in
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Instead of defining each and every little detail required to create a new document class,
% you can base your class on an existing document class.
\LoadClass{article}% or book or whatever you class is closest to

% Now paste your code from the preamble here.
% Replace \usepackage with \RequirePackage. (The syntax for both commands is the same.)

% Finally, we'll use \endinput to indicate that LaTeX can stop reading this file. LaTeX will ignore anything after this line.
\endinput
```

Note that document class files can get much more complicated (if you want to include options like `\documentclass[option]{mydocstyle}`, etc.), but this basic format should get you started.

Save your file as `mydocstyle.cls` and put it in the current directory with your `.tex` file.

You can also take a look at the [LaTeX2e for class and package writers guide](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf). It'll walk you through this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your pointer, it was enough to get me started. In this context, mentioning the command \LoadClass[options]{article} would have also been helpful.

Comment: Whoops! I meant to and forgot. I've added that into my answer so it's more helpful to others.  I've also added some code to handle options passed to the document class.